# Why this error "Package contains invalid characters" is showing up when i run the command "sencha app build native"

Tags: build, sencha-touch, native

What am i doing wrong here?

Im just trying to build my application with this command:

> sencha app build native

But i always see this error shows up:
"Package name 'karzin' contains invalid characters"

I'm using windows 7 and Sencha Touch 2.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case, if someone has the same problem... The solution is inside your json configuration file:

The string "applicationId" should be something like "com.company.AppName" and not only just a single name